# Email not working,Not able to receive email for yahoo email id

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, yahoo

I am stuck and not able to receive email from yahoo id(if the sender email id is of yahoo).
code is working fine not giving me any error and i am receiving email fromm gmail id.
i am using localhost (not in local machine on live server).
hosting server : smtp.snapgrid.com
also used authentication,enable ssl , using proper port for ssl.
on snapgrid i do check so i got is mail from yahoo is blocked and the message is,

message :

```
Type: blocked
Reason: 550 5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's    
DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if this was a legitimate 
mail. Please visit http://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC 
initiative.
```

please help...

code i used to send is(its working fine just giving for idea):

Method 1:

```
     SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new SmtpClient();
            objSMTPClient.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strSMTPServer"];
            string BODY_FORMAT = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailBodyContentFormat"];
            MailMessage objMailMessage = new MailMessage(from.Trim(), to.Trim(),   subject.Trim(), body.Trim());
            objSMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            if (BODY_FORMAT.ToUpper() == "HTML")
                objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            else if (BODY_FORMAT.ToUpper() == "TEXT")
            {
                body = StripTags(body);
                objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

                objMailMessage.Body = body.ToString().Trim();
            }
            else
                return false;
            objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMessage);
            return true;
```

Method 2:

```
            SmtpClient oMail = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress Madd = new MailAddress(from, "sunil");
            oMail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            oMail.Port = 587;
            oMail.EnableSsl = true;
            oMail.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            oMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sunil123@mydomain.com", "******");
            oMail.Timeout = 20000;
            msg.From = Madd;
            msg.Body = body.ToString();
            msg.To.Add(to);
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            oMail.Send(msg);


            return true;
```

both are working having no bug running without error....

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending via a server belonging to someone like Yahoo, Google or Office365 they expect the sender name of the account to match that that you're sending using in the from address.

For example, this would work on a your local SMTP server:

```
Message.From = new MailAddress("GrandMasterFlush@domain.com");
```

However, to get it to send via someone like Yahoo would require you to send it like this:

```
Message.From = new MailAddress("GrandMasterFlush@domain.com", "Grandmaster Flush");
```

If the sender name provided does not exactly match that of the account the email will not get sent.

Comment: yes i am also doing this.. ...  MailAddress Madd = new MailAddress(from, "Pegasus");

Comment: is it ok na for yahoo?

Comment: What's the from address you're using then? i.e. If you're sending from 'sunil.devre@mydomain.com' then from line should be: 
Message.From = new MailAddress("sunil.devre@mydomain.com", "Sunil Devre");