# Sending mail from office365 account C# mail headers

Tags: c#, email, office365, spf, dkim

I can send mail with a valid Office365 account using my C# web application to a list of opt-in addresses. So it is our own data source with our customers in it. The problem is that it is probably not received by our customers. I have send a mail from the info account to my own office365 account and pasted the headers in [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com) and got a message that my local pc is blacklisted. even when it is using the smtp of office365. We have dkim enabled and spf in the dns. What else should I do to troubleshoot this?

Here is my simple C# code for sending the mail (which works, but might needs additional anti-spam stuff?)

```
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
sc.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
sc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SmtpUsername, SmtpPassword);
sc.Port = 587;
sc.EnableSsl = true;
```

Should I add my home IP and from the office to the SPF dns entry, even when I am using the smtp of office365?

this is the value for `Authentication-Results`

> dkim=none (message not signed) header.d=none;ouroffice365domain.com; dmarc=none action=none

Is that the cause for getting on the blacklist? Please note that I am not trying to send spam. It is a valid data source where people opted in for. We are just migrated to office365 and need to send a mailing to our customers from our custom web application. We are aware of the limitations (10k per day) and 1 mail every 2 sec.

**edit** will change this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23409351/169714 because I just used the mail address and not the first and last name of the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Not having DKIM setup is not going to get you blackisted, having it set up improperly can. Your HOME PC should have nothing to do with SPF, it's the lasting sending IP which should be OFFICE 365 IP. Did you validate your DKIM and SPF by sending an email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` or `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`?

I also don't think your LOCAL PC is blacklisted, it's the IP of your INTERNET Provider that is blacklisted. Unless you have a static IP it will change.

Comment: with local ip, I meant the ip of my home network. the one I got from the isp. not local local (192.x) but the public one. Will send to both adresses to verify.